# left outer join does not display expected result in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.3, outer-join

I have two tables  one for storing the dates of mont and other for keeping attendance details of employees

in my condition  the attendance_days table has 31 records
in employee attendance  table  one employee have  29 and another employee 8 records total 37 records
data  as following

```
create table attendance_days 
(id serial primary key not null, 
attendance_date date );



INSERT INTO attendance_days  (attendance_date) VALUES ('2017-08-01');
INSERT INTO attendance_days  (attendance_date) VALUES ('2017-08-02');
INSERT INTO attendance_days  (attendance_date) VALUES ('2017-08-03');
INSERT INTO attendance_days  (attendance_date) VALUES ('2017-08-04');
INSERT INTO attendance_days  (attendance_date) VALUES ('2017-08-05');
INSERT INTO attendance_days  (attendance_date) VALUES ('2017-08-06');

INSERT INTO attendance_days  (attendance_date) VALUES ('2017-08-07');
INSERT INTO attendance_days  (attendance_date) VALUES ('2017-08-08');
INSERT INTO attendance_days  (attendance_date) VALUES ('2017-08-09');
INSERT INTO attendance_days  (attendance_date) VALUES ('2017-08-10');
INSERT INTO attendance_days  (attendance_date) VALUES ('2017-08-11');
INSERT INTO attendance_days  (attendance_date) VALUES ('2017-08-12');
INSERT INTO attendance_days  (attendance_date) VALUES ('2017-08-13');
INSERT INTO attendance_days  (attendance_date) VALUES ('2017-08-14');
INSERT INTO attendance_days  (attendance_date) VALUES ('2017-08-15');
INSERT INTO attendance_days  (attendance_date) VALUES ('2017-08-16');
INSERT INTO attendance_days  (attendance_date) VALUES ('2017-08-17');
INSERT INTO attendance_days  (attendance_date) VALUES ('2017-08-18');
INSERT INTO attendance_days  (attendance_date) VALUES ('2017-08-19');
INSERT INTO attendance_days  (attendance_date) VALUES ('2017-08-20');
INSERT INTO attendance_days  (attendance_date) VALUES ('2017-08-21');
INSERT INTO attendance_days  (attendance_date) VALUES ('2017-08-22');
INSERT INTO attendance_days  (attendance_date) VALUES ('2017-08-23');
INSERT INTO attendance_days  (attendance_date) VALUES ('2017-08-24');
INSERT INTO attendance_days  (attendance_date) VALUES ('2017-08-25');
INSERT INTO attendance_days  (attendance_date) VALUES ('2017-08-26');
INSERT INTO attendance_days  (attendance_date) VALUES ('2017-08-27');
INSERT INTO attendance_days  (attendance_date) VALUES ('2017-08-28');
INSERT INTO attendance_days  (attendance_date) VALUES ('2017-08-29');
INSERT INTO attendance_days  (attendance_date) VALUES ('2017-08-30');
INSERT INTO attendance_days  (attendance_date) VALUES ('2017-08-31');`
```

`

```
create table  employee_attendance
 (id serial primary key not null, 
 attendance_day_id integer ,
 employee_id integer,
 first_in_time timestamp,
 last_out_time timestamp );


INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES ( 1, 407, '2017-08-01 09:30:00', '2017-08-01 20:00:00');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES (2, 407, '2017-08-02 09:30:00', '2017-08-02 20:00:00');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES ( 3, 407, '2017-08-03 09:30:00', '2017-08-03 20:00:00');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES (4, 407, '2017-08-04 09:30:00', '2017-08-04 20:00:00');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES ( 5, 407, '2017-08-05 09:30:00', '2017-08-05 20:00:00');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES ( 6, 407, '2017-08-06 09:30:00', '2017-08-06 20:00:00');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES ( 7, 407, '2017-08-07 09:30:00', '2017-08-07 20:00:00');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES ( 8, 407, '2017-08-08 09:30:00', '2017-08-08 20:00:00');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES ( 9, 407, '2017-08-09 09:30:00', '2017-08-09 20:00:00');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES ( 12, 407, '2017-08-12 09:30:00', '2017-08-12 20:00:00');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES ( 13, 407, '2017-08-13 09:30:00', '2017-08-13 20:00:00');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES ( 14, 407, '2017-08-14 09:30:00', '2017-08-14 20:00:00');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES (15, 601, '2017-08-15 10:44:40', '2017-08-15 10:47:36');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES ( 15, 407, '2017-08-15 09:30:00', '2017-08-15 20:00:00');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES ( 16, 407, '2017-08-16 09:30:00', '2017-08-16 20:00:00');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES ( 17, 407, '2017-08-17 09:30:00', '2017-08-17 20:00:00');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES ( 18, 407, '2017-08-18 09:30:00', '2017-08-18 20:00:00');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES (18, 601, '2017-08-18 08:12:41', '2017-08-19 07:57:12');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES ( 19, 601, '2017-08-19 07:57:12', '2017-08-19 20:14:01');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES ( 19, 407, '2017-08-19 09:30:00', '2017-08-19 20:00:00');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES ( 20, 407, '2017-08-20 09:30:00', '2017-08-20 20:00:00');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES ( 21, 407, '2017-08-21 09:30:00', '2017-08-21 20:00:00');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES ( 22, 601, '2017-08-22 08:07:00', '2017-08-22 20:43:10');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES ( 22, 407, '2017-08-22 09:30:00', '2017-08-22 20:00:00');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES ( 23, 407, '2017-08-23 09:30:00', '2017-08-23 20:00:00');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES (24, 407, '2017-08-24 09:30:00', '2017-08-24 20:00:00');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES ( 24, 601, '2017-08-24 08:06:58', '2017-08-24 20:03:44');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES ( 25, 407, '2017-08-25 09:30:00', '2017-08-25 20:00:00');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES ( 26, 601, '2017-08-26 09:14:24', '2017-08-26 20:21:32');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES ( 26, 407, '2017-08-26 09:30:00', '2017-08-26 20:00:00');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES ( 27, 407, '2017-08-27 09:30:00', '2017-08-27 20:00:00');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES ( 27, 601, '2017-08-27 08:48:09', '2017-08-28 07:55:24');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES (28, 407, '2017-08-28 09:30:00', '2017-08-28 20:00:00');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES ( 29, 407, '2017-08-29 09:30:00', '2017-08-29 20:00:00');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES ( 29, 601, '2017-08-29 08:09:44', '2017-08-29 20:04:26');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES (30, 407, '2017-08-30 09:30:00', '2017-08-30 20:00:00');
INSERT INTO employee_attendance( attendance_day_id, employee_id, first_in_time, last_out_time) VALUES (31, 407, '2017-08-31 09:30:00', '2017-08-31 20:00:00');`
```

first table  have 31 records (31 days in aug) second table  have 37 records (29 records for employee_id 407 and 8 record for employee_id 601

I executed the following query

```
SELECT * 
FROM attendance_days
  LEFT OUTER JOIN employee_attendance 
               ON employee_attendance.attendance_day_id = attendance_days.id
```

It returns only 37 rows, but I expected 62 rows (31 rows each for  employees)

I can't understand the issue

Comment: Can you explain why you expect 62 rows?

Comment: in first table 31 rows and second table  , second table have records of  two employees

Answer (score 0):

postgres finds a matching row for each id of attendance_days, so there's no reason to create artificial hits (which would look like "id, attendance_date, null, null, null, null, null").

You are in fact expecting a result like "id, attendance_date, null, null, employee_id, null, null".

So you'll have to build a Cartesian product of  attendance_days.id and employee_id (from the "employee table") which gives you every combination of both (62 rows).
This Cartesian product can be outer joined with the employee_attendance table to yield the required result.

Comment: But if i remove the records of employee_id 407  from the employee_attendance  table it will display 31 records

Comment: Yes, 6 rows that have a matching id, and 25 rows with id's that don't match.
You are expecting a result set with the complete list of attendance_days for each employee_id and, optionally the begin and end time they were in.
This means each row should at least show: attendance_day.id, attendance_date _and_ the employee_id.

Comment: Now if you look at the result of your query (without the employee 407), you'll see that in most rows the employee_id is missing. This is why you have to (left outer) join with the Cartesian product of days and employees (the list of all combinations of employees and days).